# How to get all data from a single SQLite database column for calculating total price

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm currently making a shopping app with a shopping cart. I got the listview to display with the proper quantity and price but now have problems with trying to show the total price for checkout. There are 2 problems I'm facing :

1. How to get data from a whole column, right now I am only able to get data from the first index of the intended column.
2. When I clear the database/clear the cart, the app crashes, saying there is a null. Probably due to the cursor not able to get the read anything from the database.

**CartDatabaseHelper.java** *getCartPrice() method*

```
public Double getCartPrice() {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + CartContract.CartEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE Cart_Meal_Price";
    SQLiteDatabase dbCart;
    dbCart = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbCart.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do{if (cursor!=null) {
        Double totalPrice = cursor.getDouble(2);
        Double sum =+ totalPrice;
        return sum;
    } else {
        return 0.00;
    }}while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

**CartDataBaseHelper.java** *Declaration and Initialization of cart database*

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CartDatabase";
public static final String CART_TABLE = "CartTable";

public static final String CREATE_CART_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + CartContract.CartEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
        CartContract.CartEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        CartContract.CartEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT ," +
        CartContract.CartEntry.COLUMN_PRICE + " REAL , " +
        CartContract.CartEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY + " REAL ) " ;
```

**SummaryActivity.java** *getTotalPrice() method*

```
public void getTotalPrice() {
    cartDB = new CartDatabaseHelper(this);
    double total = cartDB.getCartPrice();
    totalprice.setText("Total Price : RM" + total);
    }
```

**SummaryActivity.java** *Clear database onClickListener*

```
clearthedata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int deletethedata = getContentResolver().delete(CartContract.CartEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
            cartDB = new CartDatabaseHelper(context);
            double total = cartDB.getCartPrice();
            if (cartDB != null) {
                totalprice.setText("Total Price : RM" + total);
            } else {
                totalprice.setText("Total Price : RM0.00");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the sum of all the values of the column `CartContract.CartEntry.COLUMN_PRICE` in the table, then you need a query like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(price), 0) FROM tablename
```

Here `COALESCE()` is used to return `0` just in case the table is empty.

So your code should be:

```
public double getCartPrice() {
    String query = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(" + CartContract.CartEntry.COLUMN_PRICE + "), 0) FROM " + CartContract.CartEntry.TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase dbCart = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbCart.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    double total = cursor.getDouble(0);
    cursor.close();
    dbCart.close();
    return total;
}
```

If you want to delete all the rows of the table, then:

```
SQLiteDatabase dbCart = this.getWritableDatabase();
dbCart.delete(CartContract.CartEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
```

Comment: It works, but it crashed when I clicked on the Clear Database button. So I had to remove everything and leave the `dbCart.delete` and  `totalprice.setText("Total Price : RM0.00");`. And then it worked perfectly.